# Outputs a char array with one less character everytime it loops

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++. Trying out a simple question:

> Create a while loop that outputs a char array with one less character
>   every time it loops until it holds only '\0' values within it.

The answer is :

```
char s[] = "Hello World";
while (strlen(s))
{
    s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

However I do not under the use of strlen. 
Especially this part : `s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';` 
Can someone explain what this part mean?

And lastly is there another way to solve this question?

Comment: `s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';` sets the terminating c-string character to one less position it was before.

Comment: [Do you know what strlen does?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen)

Comment: He you looked up what `strlen` does?

Comment: Your code doesn't print the whole string. Is it intentional? Is it part of the requirements?

Comment: Use std::string, not char arrays!

Comment: @Simple and Carcigenicate, I read up about it, length of string...right?

Comment: @Stefano Buora, the requirement is to print the in loop the character will reduce by 1 character everytime.

Comment: @manni66 , I know string is better but then the question say use char array

Comment: That doesn't speak for the questioner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone already answered, `s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';` it's a way to shorten the string moving backward the null ('\0') character at the end of the string.

As you are asking about another way to do the same thing, here two examples:

Trying to avoid a double call to strlen in ever loop:

```
   char p[] = "Hello World";
    char* pEnd = &p[strlen(p)];
    while (p!=pEnd)
    {
        *--pEnd = '\0';
        cout << p << endl;
    }
```

A more modern approach keeping the mainline you drawn with your example:

```
std::string str("Hello World");
while(str.length() > 0) {
    str.pop_back();
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

*(2nd solution updated thanks to @Simple contribution)*

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Some questions about 1st solution:
I don't understand `while (p!=pEnd)`, it mean p not equal to `pEnd` but that will be false, then the loop will not executed. Correct me if I am wrong.

and for 2nd solution:
By using string, it will not contain `\0` right?

Comment: `str.resize(str.length()-1);` is `str.pop_back();`

Comment: @engkhsky, that's a good question though (about \0 in the string object). I believe for the sake of speed it may be in, but, but.. in order to access to the string as a standard array of (const) char (or a const char*), you need to access through c_str(). So I believe the answer is: you cannot assume that the internal rappresentation in a std:string of a string is an array of char null terminated. As the std library is always trying to be very efficent I believe for the sake of mind that it's internal rappresentation include an \0 at the end, but do not assume it while you are coding.

Answer (score 1):

A c-string has a null terminator (i.e. `\0`) so in your case you string is actually:

```
H e l l o   W o r l d \0
```

`strlen` counts the number of characters upto the **first** null terminator (`\0`) so your initial length is 11.  Every time you run your while loop you march the null character back one so:

```
H e l l o   W o r l \0 \0
H e l l o   W o r \0 \0 \0
H e l l o   W o \0 \0 \0 \0
```

which in essence reduces the size of `strlen`.

Similarly `cout` prints up to first null terminator (`\0`) .

Another thing to note is `strlen` returns the count of characters however a c-string is 0 based which is why the `-1` is in `s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';` (to point to the last character in the c-string).

Comment: Thank you for explaining! for `s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';` the content inside `[ ]` is the index of array right?

Answer (score 0):

strlen get the length of your string.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/

'\0' is a null terminating character

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

So basically your going through your string and making it so that it terminates with null one character earlier every time

Comment: There a few codes to show the length of string or char right?
such as `str.size` and `str.length`
,and i see `size_t`, which I don't understand how it works.

Comment: So str.length() works for strings.http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/ . and str.size() works for arrays http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/size/

Comment: and here is the reference for size_t.  I dont use that one that much http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t